# View.getView() returns null

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to find my folder or view in my database. Which named **Team Documents** this folder has some filter option like **By Date**, **By Category**. But this returns me a null even the folder already exists.

```
String dbServer = "d23dbm95/23/A/IBM", dbFileName = "dbom\\farizan\\stsklb1.nsf";


public void runNotes()
{
    Session session = null;
    Database db = null;
    View view = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try
    {
        NotesThread.sinitThread();
        session = NotesFactory.createSession();
        System.out.println("User = " + session.getUserName());
        db = session.getDatabase(dbServer, dbFileName);

        if(db.isOpen())
        {
            System.out.println("Title "+db.getTitle());

            view = db.getView("Team Documents \\ By Date");


            if(view == null)
            {
                System.out.println("still null");
            }

        }

    }
    catch(NotesException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried also to fill my `getView()` method like **Team Documents**. But still returns a null. Any approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would have been more helpful if you had included a link to a screenshot of your Domino Designer client's folder list, my best guess is that you have two folders, not one folder with "filter options". Also, my guess is that "Team Documents" is not actually a folder; it's just a prefix on the folder names that makes them *appear* to be nested in a parent folder.

If that's the case, you would need

```
iew = db.getView("Team Documents\\By Category");
```

Or

```
iew = db.getView("Team Documents\\By Date");
```

Note: No spaces before & after the backslashes.

If my assumptions above are not correct, then my suggestion would be to assign alias names to the folders in Domino Designer and use the aliases instead of the display names in your code. Frankly, that's *always* a good practice, because it allows your code to continue working even if you decide to change the display names.

Comment: I would add that you need to be careful with your terminology.  Folders are not Views and Views are not Folders.

Comment: True! But from the Notes classes perspective, they look the same.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz you did the trick! :) I'll tried to add also a alias for my folder in order to still get the right folder. Appreciated your help!